Maximizing area of two identical circles being cut out from a triangle.
You are given a triangular metal sheet, and you need to cut two identical circular shapes from it. How should you cut them to maximize the area of the circles?
I think the circles should be tangent to two sides and eachother, but I don't know how to continue.
This problem is from a university enterence mock problem sheet.
And like I said I have no idea how to solve it.
Appriciate any help.
Edit:
So far I found out the relation on the picture from the square being the inscribed square of the smaller (thinner) triangle.

Now I need to connect c to AB.

How would one prove your first conjecture (that the circles’ centers lie on angle bisectors)? And for any triangle $\triangle ABC$ you have only three pairs of angles to try, so you could even do it exhaustively by brute force.

Yes that claim was dumb I edited my question.

If the triangle is equilateral, this is known: see the compendium here for cases up to 15 squares. Results are also known for an isosceles right triangle (see here.) If the triangle is arbitrary I suspect the problem is considerably harder.

Arbitrary triangle
